# What is the dual of a variable that is not in the constaint but in the cost function

Tags: linear-programming, duality-theorems

Suppose you have the following LP where c is a constant.
$$ \min cx_1 + x_2$$
$$x_2 = 1 $$
$$ x_1, x_2 \geq 0$$
What is the dual of this LP problem?
If I pad zeros, I would get something like
$$\max p_1$$
$$p_1 \leq 1$$
$$0p_1 \leq c \implies 0 \leq c$$
$$p1 free$$
$0 \leq c$ as a constraint seem quite absurd to me, as c is a constant defined in the question. What if c is negative, the constraint won't even make sense.

Answer (score 1):

$0 \le c$ is absurd, but it is the correct constraint. That's not surprising, because a primal variable that doesn't appear in any of the constraints is also absurd.

What if $c$ is negative? In that case, the constraint *does* make sense, it simply can never be satisfied. That makes the dual infeasible. This is appropriate, because if $c$ is negative, the primal is unbounded: the point $(t,1)$ has objective value $ct+1$, and as $t \to \infty$, $ct+1 \to -\infty$.

What if $c$ is positive? In that case, the constraint $0 \le c$ is always satisfied, and can be ignored. This is appropriate, because in the primal, the variable $x_1$ can be ignored: the $cx_1$ term is minimized when we set $x_1=0$, and there are no constraints to stop us from doing that, so we will always set $x_1=0$.